# PHP - Show result in same page

Tags: php

I have 2 pages which named `checkresult.php` and `checkresult2.php`. User can fill in the data in `checkresult.php` and then the result will be shown in `checkresult2.php`. I wish to combine these 2 pages in `checkresult.php`, how can I display my result below the table once I click "Check my qualifications!" button? (Without influence displaying error message (in Line 95 and Line 129))

checkresult.php

```
<form name="checkQ" action="checkresult2.php" method="post">
    <table class="p1" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" bordercolor="#000000" align="center" width="905" border="2">
          <tr>
              <td><div align="center"><strong>No.</strong></div></td>
              <td><div align="center"><strong>Subject Name</strong></div></td>
              <td><div align="center"><strong>Grade</strong></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td width="40"><div align="center">1</div></td>
              <td width="700">
                  <b>BAHASA MELAYU</b>
              </td>
              <td width="165"><div align="center">
                  <select id="grade_opt1" name="grad1">
                      <option value="0">- Select grade -</option>
                          <?php
                          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_grade");
                          while($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                          {?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $g['grade']; ?>"><?php echo $g["grade"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td width="42"><div align="center">2</div></td>
              <td width="539">
                  <b>BAHASA INGGERIS</b>
              </td>
              <td width="166"><div align="center">
                  <select id="grade_opt2" name="grad2">
                      <option value="0">- Select grade -</option>
                          <?php
                          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_grade");
                          while($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                          {?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $g['grade']; ?>"><?php echo $g["grade"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td width="42"><div align="center">3</div></td>
              <td width="539">
                  <b>SEJARAH</b>
              </td>
              <td width="166"><div align="center">
                  <select id="grade_opt3" name="grad3">
                      <option value="0">- Select grade -</option>
                          <?php
                          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_grade");
                          while($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                          {?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $g['grade']; ?>"><?php echo $g["grade"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td width="42"><div align="center">4</div></td>
              <td width="539">
                 <b>MATEMATIK</b>
              </td>
              <td width="166"><div align="center">
                  <select id="grade_opt4" name="grad4">
                      <option value="0">- Select grade -</option>
                          <?php
                          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_grade");
                          while($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                          {?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $g['grade']; ?>"><?php echo $g["grade"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td width="42"><div align="center">5</div></td>
              <td width="539">
                  <input id="subject_opt5" name="subject_opt5" class="subjects" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Type to search subject name"/>
                 <?php
                 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {
                            $subj05 = $_POST['subject_opt5'];
                            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM spm_subject WHERE name='$subj05'";
                            $error01 = "<font color='#FF0000'>Subject <strong>".$_POST['subject_opt5']."</strong> doesn't found in database!</font>";
                            $checkdb1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql1));
                            if(!($subj05 == ""))
                            {
                            if(!$checkdb1 == 1)
                            {
                                echo $error01;
                            }
                            }
                        }
                ?>
              </td>
              <td width="166"><div align="center">
                  <select id="grade_opt5" name="grad5">
                      <option value="0">- Select grade -</option>
                          <?php
                          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_grade");
                          while($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                          {?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $g['grade']; ?>"><?php echo $g["grade"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td width="42"><div align="center">6</div></td>
              <td width="539">
                  <input id="subject_opt6" name="subject_opt6" class="subjects" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Type to search subject name"/>
                  <?php
                  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {
                            $subj06 = $_POST['subject_opt6'];
                            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM spm_subject WHERE name='$subj06'";
                            $error02 = "<font color='#FF0000'>Subject <strong>".$_POST['subject_opt6']."</strong> doesn't found in database!</font>";
                            $checkdb2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql2));
                            if(!($subj06 == ""))
                            {
                                if(!$checkdb2 == 1)
                                {
                                    echo $error02;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            }
                        }
                ?>
              </td>
              <td width="166"><div align="center">
                  <select id="grade_opt6" name="grad6">
                      <option value="0">- Select grade -</option>
                          <?php
                          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_grade");
                          while($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                          {?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $g['grade']; ?>"><?php echo $g["grade"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                  <div align="center">
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check my qualifications!">
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

checkresult2.php

```
<?php
    //BM
    $g1 = $_POST['grad1'];
    switch ($g1)
    {
        case 'A+':
        case 'A':
        case 'A-':
        case 'B+':
        case 'B':
        case 'C+':
        case 'C':
            check1();
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'G':
            result_nq_all();
            break;
        default:
            result_nq_all();
            break;
    }   

    //BI
    function check1()
    {
        $g2 = $_POST['grad2'];
        switch ($g2)
        {
            case 'A+':
            case 'A':
            case 'A-':
            case 'B+':
            case 'B':
            case 'C+':
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
                check2();
                break;
            case 'G':
                result_nq_all();
                break;
            default:
                result_nq_all();
                break;
        }   
    }

    //SJ
    function check2()
    {
        $g3 = $_POST['grad3'];
        switch ($g3)
        {
            case 'A+':
            case 'A':
            case 'A-':
            case 'B+':
            case 'B':
            case 'C+':
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
                check3();
                break;
            case 'G':
                result_nq_all();
                break;
            default:
                result_nq_all();
                break;
        }   
    }

    //MT
    function check3()
    {
        $g4 = $_POST['grad4'];
        switch ($g4)
        {
            case 'A+':
            case 'A':
            case 'A-':
            case 'B+':
            case 'B':
            case 'C+':
            case 'C':
                check4();
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'G':
                result_nq_all();
                break;
            default:
                result_nq_all();
                break;
        }   
    }

    function check4()
    {
        $g2 = $_POST['grad2'];
        $g3 = $_POST['grad3'];
        $g5 = $_POST['grad5'];
        $g6 = $_POST['grad6'];

        if($g2 == "A+" || $g2 == "A"  || $g2 == "A-"  || $g2 == "B+" || $g2 == "B" || $g2 == "C+" || $g2 == "C")
        {
            if($g3 == "A+" || $g3 == "A"  || $g3 == "A-"  || $g3 == "B+" || $g3 == "B" || $g3 == "C+" || $g3 == "C")
            {
                if($g5 == "A+" || $g5 == "A"  || $g5 == "A-"  || $g5 == "B+" || $g5 == "B" || $g5 == "C+" || $g5 == "C")
                {
                    if($g6 == "A+" || $g6 == "A"  || $g6 == "A-"  || $g6 == "B+" || $g6 == "B" || $g6 == "C+" || $g6 == "C")
                    {
                        result_q_all();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_q_all();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if($g6 == "A+" || $g6 == "A"  || $g6 == "A-"  || $g6 == "B+" || $g6 == "B" || $g6 == "C+" || $g6 == "C")
                    {
                        result_q_all();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_q_conven_only();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($g5 == "A+" || $g5 == "A"  || $g5 == "A-"  || $g5 == "B+" || $g5 == "B" || $g5 == "C+" || $g5 == "C")
                {
                    if($g6 == "A+" || $g6 == "A"  || $g6 == "A-"  || $g6 == "B+" || $g6 == "B" || $g6 == "C+" || $g6 == "C")
                    {
                        result_q_all();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_q_conven_only();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if($g6 == "A+" || $g6 == "A"  || $g6 == "A-"  || $g6 == "B+" || $g6 == "B" || $g6 == "C+" || $g6 == "C")
                    {
                        result_q_conven_only();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_nq_all();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($g3 == "A+" || $g3 == "A"  || $g3 == "A-"  || $g3 == "B+" || $g3 == "B" || $g3 == "C+" || $g3 == "C")
            {
                if($g5 == "A+" || $g5 == "A"  || $g5 == "A-"  || $g5 == "B+" || $g5 == "B" || $g5 == "C+" || $g5 == "C")
                {
                    if($g6 == "A+" || $g6 == "A"  || $g6 == "A-"  || $g6 == "B+" || $g6 == "B" || $g6 == "C+" || $g6 == "C")
                    {
                        result_q_all();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_q_conven_only();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if($g6 == "A+" || $g6 == "A"  || $g6 == "A-"  || $g6 == "B+" || $g6 == "B" || $g6 == "C+" || $g6 == "C")
                    {
                        result_q_conven_only();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_nq_all();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($g5 == "A+" || $g5 == "A"  || $g5 == "A-"  || $g5 == "B+" || $g5 == "B" || $g5 == "C+" || $g5 == "C")
                {
                    if($g6 == "A+" || $g6 == "A"  || $g6 == "A-"  || $g6 == "B+" || $g6 == "B" || $g6 == "C+" || $g6 == "C")
                    {
                        result_q_conven_only();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_nq_all();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if($g6 == "A+" || $g6 == "A"  || $g6 == "A-"  || $g6 == "B+" || $g6 == "B" || $g6 == "C+" || $g6 == "C")
                    {
                        result_nq_all();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_nq_all();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function result_q_all()
    {?>
        <br><br>
        <table width="638" border='1' align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='width:auto'>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#000000" colspan='2'><div align="center"><font color="#FFFF00"><strong>PREMIER POLYTECHNICS</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="416"><div align="center"><strong>Programme Name</strong></div></td>
                <td width="170"><div align="center"><strong>Result</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign='middle'>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIP">Diploma in Information Technology (Programming)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong> <img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DNS">Diploma in Information Technology (Networking)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIS">Diploma in Information Technology (Information Security)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#000000" colspan='2'><div align="center"><font color="#FFFF00"><strong>CONVENTIONAL POLYTECHNICS / METrO</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="center"><strong>Programme Name</strong></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong>Result</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIP">Diploma in Information Technology (Programming)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DNS">Diploma in Information Technology (Networking)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIS">Diploma in Information Technology (Information Security)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php }

    function result_q_conven_only()
    {?>
        <br><br>
        <table width="638" border='1' align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='width:auto'>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#000000" colspan='2'><div align="center"><font color="#FFFF00"><strong>PREMIER POLYTECHNICS</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="416"><div align="center"><strong>Programme Name</strong></div></td>
                <td width="170"><div align="center"><strong>Result</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign='middle'>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIP">Diploma in Information Technology (Programming)</a></td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong> <img src="img/no.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DNS">Diploma in Information Technology (Networking)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/no.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIS">Diploma in Information Technology (Information Security)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/no.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#000000" colspan='2'><div align="center"><font color="#FFFF00"><strong>CONVENTIONAL POLYTECHNICS / METrO</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="center"><strong>Programme Name</strong></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong>Result</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIP">Diploma in Information Technology (Programming)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DNS">Diploma in Information Technology (Networking)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIS">Diploma in Information Technology (Information Security)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src="img/yes.png" style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#090">QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php }

    function result_nq_all()
    { ?>
        <br><br>
        <table width="638" border='1' align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='width:auto'>
            <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#000000" colspan='2'><div align="center"><font color="#FFFF00"><strong>PREMIER POLYTECHNICS</strong></div></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="416"><div align="center"><strong>Programme Name</strong></div></td>
                <td width="170"><div align="center"><strong>Result</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign='middle'>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIP">Diploma in Information Technology (Programming)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong> <img src='img/no.png' style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DNS">Diploma in Information Technology (Networking)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src='img/no.png' style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIS">Diploma in Information Technology (Information Security)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src='img/no.png' style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#000000" colspan='2'><div align="center"><font color="#FFFF00"><strong>CONVENTIONAL POLYTECHNICS / METrO</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="center"><strong>Programme Name</strong></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong>Result</strong></div></td
            ></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIP">Diploma in Information Technology (Programming)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src='img/no.png' style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DNS">Diploma in Information Technology (Networking)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src='img/no.png' style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="programme_view.php?programme_code=DIS">Diploma in Information Technology (Information Security)</td>
                <td><div align="center"><strong><img src='img/no.png' style='vertical-align:middle'/>&nbsp;<span style="color:#F00">NOT QUALIFIED</span></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<?php } ?>
```

P/S : Can ignore the coding for `checkresult2.php` since it's quite long... LOL

Comment: Add `checkresult2.php` php script in top of `checkresult.php` and in form action instead of `checkresult2.php` use `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>`

Comment: Hi @Haridarshan Thanks for your guide. But I face to this problem again:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function result_nq_all()**

Comment: in your function result_nq_all() you need to echo html code in string format instead of putting html code directly in function definition. `echo "<br><br>
        <table width="638" border='1' align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='width:auto'>....</table>";`

Comment: I was tried:

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 if($error01 == "")
 {
  if($error02 == "")
  {`
in order to show the result IF THERE IS NO ERROR SHOWN... but it is not work... BTW... your solution for showing result is work for me... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change line from `checkresult.php`

```
<form name="checkQ" action="checkresult2.php" method="post">
```

to

```
<form name="checkQ" action="#" method="post">
```

and Add your `checkresult2.php` code in `checkresult.php`

Rahul Dambare

Comment: Hi @Rahul Dambare Thanks for your guide. But I face to this problem again: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function result_nq_all()** when I click "Check my qualifications!" button

Comment: It happens because you are declaring the function after trying to call it. First defined function definition and then call it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the action page name that it:

```
<form name="checkQ" action="" method="post">
<!--                        ^remove the name of file from here-->
```

Comment: Hi @Kausha Thanks for your guide. But I face to this problem again: Fatal error: Call to undefined function result_nq_all() when I click "Check my qualifications!" button

Answer (score 1):

1- Remove the action value: `<form name="checkQ" action="" method="post">`

2- Add the contents of `checkresult2.php` in the beginning of `checkresult.php, get the functions out, and wrap the rest with an if condition.

```
//checkresult2.php contents except the lines inside the if statement below

if (isset($_POST['grad1'])) {
    // only this section from checkresult2.php to be under the if statement, the functions should be outside this scope
    //BM
    $g1 = $_POST['grad1'];
    switch ($g1) {
        case 'A+':
        case 'A':
        case 'A-':
        case 'B+':
        case 'B':
        case 'C+':
        case 'C':
            check1();
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'G':
            result_nq_all();
            break;
        default:
            result_nq_all();
            break;
    }
} else {

    // content of checkresult.php

}
```

Comment: Hi @Em Thanks for your guide. But I face to this problem again: Fatal error: Call to undefined function result_nq_all() when I click "Check my qualifications!" button

Comment: I was tried: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { if($error01 == "") { if($error02 == "") {` in order to show the result IF THERE IS NO ERROR SHOWN... but it is not work...